# Authenticated Rest calls in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have enables authentication in `Zeppelin`. I am able to authenticate Zeppelin from curl:

```
curl -i --data 'userName=admin&password=admin' -X POST http://ip_address:port/api/login
```

It is giving me response properly with `JSESSIONID`.

How can I use the same session in my next API calls like

```
http://ip_address:port/api/notebook
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Write the response cookies to local file during login api call

`curl -c cookies.txt -i --data 'userName=admin&password=admin' -X POST http://ip_address:port/api/login`

and pass the cookies to next API calls

`curl -b cookies.txt http://ip_address:port/api/notebook`

Comment: i want to do it without using cookies.txt

Answer (score 0):

Example for run note

```
curl -i -b 'JSESSIONID=ad51301f-a13b-4b8d-a6c7-b684dc453f8f; Path=/; HttpOnly' -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://ip_address:port/api/notebook/job/note_id
```